# Regex Works in Perl, Doesn't as NSRegularExpresson

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I have this regex:

```
([^\ \t\r\n\[\{\(\-])?'(?(1)|(?=\s | s\b))
```

with the following substitution:

```
$1&#8217;
```

This seems to work in Perl. Given a phrase like "King Solomon's Mines," it will change it to `King Solomon&#8217;s Mines`, but it throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error as an `NSRegularExpression`. [This test suite](http://regex101.com/#pcre) suggests that syntax is valid in php and Python but not Javascript, and that the `(?(1)` part is the culprit.

Example Swift code:

```
let string = "King Solomon's Mines"
var anError: NSError? = nil
let pattern = "([^\\ \\t\\r\\n\\[\\{\\(\\-])?'(?(1)|(?=\\s | s\\b))"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &anError)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, countElements(string))
let template = "$1&#8217;"
let newString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: range, withTemplate: template)
```

The `let regex` declaration is where a Playground will get the bad access error. Do I need to modify the regex to get it working in Swift?

(Edit: forgot to put in the escapes for the backslashes. I had that in my code.)

Comment: You want to replace `'` with `&#8217;`?

Comment: The `let pattern = ...` line does not compile at all (several "invalid escape sequence in literal" errors).

Comment: Are you trying to use that regex exactly? NSRegularExpression uses ICU regex, not Perl regex. There are differences between the two flavors, as well as the need to escape some of the string in Swift, such as the backslashes. Make sure that the regex matches both the ICU regex syntax as well as the escaping needed by Swift strings.

Comment: Oh, I had the backslashes escaped in my code. I just pasted it in from the string's output instead of my code. I've edited the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the conditional test `(?(1)...|...)` is available, but it is not really a problem since it is not needed. This pattern does the same:

```
let pattern = "'(?:(?<=[^\\s[{(-]')|(?=\\s | s\\b))"
```

Note: if it doesn't work, try to double escape the opening square bracket in the character class.

Comment: That pattern, with double backslashes before the first `[`, does fix the error but it doesn't work replace the `'` with `&#8217;`

Comment: @davextreme: Note that since there is no more capture group in this pattern, the replacement must be: `let template = "&#8217;"`.

Comment: Solved it: the whitespace in `s | s` was causing the problem. Taking it out or adding .AllowCommentsAndWhitespace did the trick: `let pattern = "'(?:(?<=[^\\s[{(-]')|(?=\\s | s\\b))"` and `let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive | .AllowCommentsAndWhitespace, error: &anError)`